# Python download files to a specific directory using open with format in the file name

Tags: python, directory, path

I am trying to download files to a specific folder, but with formats in the file name according to its data in the spreadsheet.

For example, I have data columns with year, country, language, and a link to a file. (e.g., 2014, China, Chinese, http://example.pdf). I want to download all pdf files to a specific folder with its name of values from other columns (e.g., C:/Users/Me/Python/folder/2014_China_Chinese.pdf).

Below is what's undesired but successful because this saves to a default folder.

```
for r in range(2, ws.max_row+1):
        with open("{}_{}_{}.pdf".\
                  format(ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value, ws.cell(row=r, column=2).value, ws.cell(row=r, column=3).value), "wb") as f:
            f.write(pdf_res.content)
```

Below is what's desired but unsuccessful.

```
    with open(r'C:/Users/Me/Python/folder/{}_{}_{}.pdf'.\
              format(ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value, ws.cell(row=r, column=2).value, ws.cell(row=r, column=3).value), "wb") as f:
        f.write(pdf_res.content)
```

This is what I want to do but obviously with 'r' and directory, all the formats are not allowed.

What's my option?

Comment: Perhaps not related, but why aren't you using `.value` for the first `cell()`?

Comment: @JohnGordon You're right. It's a typo. All three are cell().value. Just edited. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: What is the actual problem with the second example?